# hide row numbers in jqgrid by using column chooser

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Iam using column chooser to hide columns, but when iam clikcking hide all columns row numbers are displaying how to hide row numbers also, please anyone help me on this, thanks

this is my code:

```
 $("#list1").jqGrid({
    url:"./controllers/apGetTestData.php?testanzres=1&testsuite="+testsuite+"&testcase="+testcase+"&ch="+ch+,  
    datatype: 'xml', 
    mtype: 'GET', 
    height: 'auto',
    colNames:[ 'RRID', 'Release Tag','Completed Date'],
    colModel:[
             {name:'idreleaseRequest', index:'idreleaseRequest', width:24},
             {name:'releaseRequestTag', index:'releaseRequestTag'},
             {name:'timeStamp', index:'timeStamp'},
             {name:'DateInfo', index:'Date Info', sortable:false,align:'center'}
             ],       
    pager: $('#pager1'), 
    rowNum:6, 
    rowList:[6,12,18,24],
    sortname: 'timeStamp',
    sortorder: "ASC",
    caption:"Test Results",
    shrinkToFit:true,
    autowidth: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    rownumbers:true,
    cloneToTop:true,
    toppager:true
 }).trigger("reloadGrid");
     $("#list1").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager1',{add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false,  
          cloneToTop:true,refresh: false});
          $.extend(true, $.ui.multiselect, {
                    locale: {
                        addAll: 'Make all visible',
                        removeAll: 'Hide All',
                        itemsCount: 'Avlialble Columns'
                    }
                });
                $.extend(true, $.jgrid.col, {
                    width: 450,
                    modal: true,
                    msel_opts: {dividerLocation: 0.5},
                    dialog_opts: {
                        minWidth: 470,
                        show: 'blind',
                        hide: 'explode'
                    }
                });
                $("#list1").jqGrid('navButtonAdd',$('#list1')[0].id + '_toppager_left', {
                    caption: "Customize Columns",
                    buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator",
                    title: "Customize Columns",
                    onClickButton: function () {

                    }
                });
          var topPagerDiv = $(('#list1')[0] .id+ '_toppager')[0];         

          $(('#list1') + "_toppager_center", topPagerDiv).remove(); 
          $(('#list1') + "_toppager_right", topPagerDiv).remove();        

          $("table.ui-jqgrid-htable thead").appendTo("table#list1");
          $("table#list1 thead tr").addClass('floatingHeaderRow');
          $("div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv").width($(window).width()+30);
```

i am using row numbers true option, but i want to hide row numbers when iam clicking hide all in column chooser

Comment: please share relevant code that you have tried so far

Comment: Hi Bhushan Kawadkar, i added the relevant code please suggest me any idea on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the column "rn" created by `rownumbers: true` in the list of columns visible by `columnChooser` by executing

```
$("#list1").jqGrid("setColProp", "rn", {hidedlg: false});
```

but you create in the way other problems. The column "rn" is special column which you should not move to another position.

If you need to hide the whole grid then I would recommend you to use

```
$("#list1").closest(".ui-jqgrid").hide();
```

and show it by

```
$("#list1").closest(".ui-jqgrid").show();
```

If you need to hide or make visible only the `"rn"` column you can use `showCol`/`hideCol`. For example

```
$("#list1").jqGrid("hideCol", "rn");
```

Comment: Hi oleg i am not very clear about this could you please provide me any demo about this, and thanks for your reply

Comment: Hi oleg thanks it is working perfectly , could you please tell me how to give column name for row numbers

Comment: @Sravya: you are welcome! You asked me "how to give column name for row numbers?". Probably you mean "how to give column name by the column number?". In the case you can get `colModel`: `var cm = $("#list1").jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel")` and the name of the column `iCol` will be `cm[iCol].name`.

Comment: Hi oleg, i am not clear about this, i want to set column name for row numbers as sno, could you please give me clear solution, and thanks  for your support on jqgrid